# "Types of property 'X' are incompatible" but it is not

Tags: typescript

I tried to create an object of an interface with properties initialized from another object like that:

```
id: data.reference.id
```

The properties are compatible, but typescript compiler throws an error. I don't understand why and how to avoid this error.

(a link to test the code can be found after)

```
// INTERFACES AND TYPES
type CategoryOne = 1
type CategoryTwo = 2
type Category = CategoryOne | CategoryTwo

interface ReferenceOne {
    id: string,
    type: CategoryOne
}

interface ReferenceTwo {
    id: string,
    type: CategoryTwo
}

type Reference = ReferenceOne |  ReferenceTwo

// DIRECT INIT
let reference_OK: Reference = { // works here
    id: '1',
    type: 1
}

// INIT FROM DATA
interface Data {
    reference: {
        id: string,
        type: Category
    }
}

let data: Data = {
    reference: {
        id: '1',
        type: 1
    }
}

let reference_KO: Reference = { // <--- error here
    id: data.reference.id,      // but compatible property
    type: data.reference.type   // but compatible property
}

let param: Category = data.reference.type // == 1

let reference_KO2: Reference = { // <--- error here
    id: data.reference.id,       // but compatible property
    type: param                  // but compatible property
}

param = 1 // == data.reference.type, same variable

let reference_OK2: Reference = { // <--- no error here
    id: data.reference.id,
    type: param
}
```

[this code in Typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=%2F%2F%20INTERFACES%20AND%20TYPES%0D%0Atype%20CategoryOne%20%3D%201%0D%0Atype%20CategoryTwo%20%3D%202%0D%0Atype%20Category%20%3D%20CategoryOne%20%7C%20CategoryTwo%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20ReferenceOne%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20id%3A%20string%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20type%3A%20CategoryOne%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20ReferenceTwo%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20id%3A%20string%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20type%3A%20CategoryTwo%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20Reference%20%3D%20ReferenceOne%20%7C%20%C2%A0ReferenceTwo%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20DIRECT%20INIT%0D%0Alet%20reference_OK%3A%20Reference%20%3D%20%7B%20%2F%2F%20works%20here%0D%0A%20%20%20%20id%3A%20'1'%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20type%3A%201%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20INIT%20FROM%20DATA%0D%0Ainterface%20Data%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20reference%3A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20id%3A%20string%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20type%3A%20Category%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20data%3A%20Data%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20reference%3A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20id%3A%20'1'%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20type%3A%201%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20reference_KO%3A%20Reference%20%3D%20%7B%20%2F%2F%20%3C---%20error%20here%0D%0A%20%20%20%20id%3A%20data.reference.id%2C%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20but%20compatible%20property%0D%0A%20%20%20%20type%3A%20data.reference.type%20%20%20%2F%2F%20but%20compatible%20property%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20param%3A%20Category%20%3D%20data.reference.type%20%2F%2F%20%3D%3D%201%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20reference_KO2%3A%20Reference%20%3D%20%7B%20%2F%2F%20%3C---%20error%20here%0D%0A%20%20%20%20id%3A%20data.reference.id%2C%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20but%20compatible%20property%0D%0A%20%20%20%20type%3A%20param%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20but%20compatible%20property%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aparam%20%3D%201%20%2F%2F%20%3D%3D%20data.reference.type%2C%20same%20variable%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20reference_OK2%3A%20Reference%20%3D%20%7B%20%2F%2F%20%3C---%20no%20error%20here%0D%0A%20%20%20%20id%3A%20data.reference.id%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20type%3A%20param%0D%0A%7D)

**[update]** I added the case when a new reference is created from a variable (reference_KO2 - variable initialized from a property of data - and reference_OK2 - same variable initialized with a constant)

> two behaviors with the same variable of a compatible type !

Answer (score 6):

While the code appears to be semantically correct, the compiler will disagree because `Data` does not retain additional information about the category underneath: it only knows that the field `type` is a `Category`.

So, we know that `reference_ok` can be assigned either a `ReferenceOne` or a `ReferenceTwo`. `ReferenceOne` requires `type` to be a `CategoryOne`, whereas `ReferenceTwo` requires `type` to be a `CategoryTwo`. Neither of these work, since `data.reference.type` is a generalized `Category`. We could reproduce the same effect with less code, by "upcasting" the value on purpose:

```
let r: Reference = {
  id: '1',
  type: 1 as Category,
}
```

There are at least two ways to avoid this situation. One of them is to redefine `Reference` as an interface, which basically tells the compiler that we don't need to know the category in compile time at this point.

```
interface Reference {
    id: string,
    type: Category,
}
```

The most appealing solution, however, is with generics. We can augment `Data` to also contain the type of the category:

```
interface Data<C extends Category> {
    reference: {
        id: string,
        type: C
    }
}
```

At this point, this code works:

```
let data: Data<CategoryOne> = {
    reference: {
        id: '1',
        type: 1
    }
}

let reference_KO: Reference = {
    id: data.reference.id,
    type: data.reference.type
}
```

The same treatment can be applied to `Reference`, if so you wish.

Comment: thanks for your response; in my case, the variable of type Data can handle the two types ("one" and "two"), so I can't use generic; and I don't want to use an interface for Reference, but an union type because I want to define my code as my business vocabulary

Comment: Those constraints represent a change of intent in your question. In particular, you haven't explained properly why `Reference` has to be a union. Please update your question with further details on that end. Do note however that it may currently be impossible to achieve what you are asking now.